# Resize my robot (or map)

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I was searching, but can not find a solution. Maybe I not using rights words for a right search.

I have a simulation in gazebo with a map and a robot, I call my simulation via Roslaunch.

And I need to make my robot start on simulation a little smaller than now, but I do not know in which file I need change the code for that.

Can someone tell me what type of file I need to open for that change?
If you guys need, I can give the github link of my simulation, but I think there is some type o default file for that.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253127/resize-my-robot-(or-map)/) by [vcanato](https://answers.ros.org/users/29088/vcanato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-01-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vcanato](https://answers.ros.org/users/29088/vcanato/) on 2017-01-28**:
I have found something like proportion, but didn´t work

And the only "size´s" number i have found are zero by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The size of your robot is defined by the URDF or SDF file, so you'll need to change the size there.

Of course, it's a lot more complicated than just a single scaling parameter, because you'll have to scale each of the links, meshes, and collision meshes for each link, and if you have the mass or inertia of your robot defined, it would be wise to scale those too.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vcanato](https://answers.ros.org/users/29088/vcanato/) on 2017-01-29**:
Man, this look really complicated hahahaha
But I will study and try.

You know if change the map size is easier?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-01-29**:
If the world is less complicated than robot, it's probably easier to scale the world.